# Split string to keywords in dart

Tags: flutter, dart

If I have a string that says "This is a good example", is there any way to split it to the following output in dart:

```
This
This is
This is a
This is a good
This is a good example
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
String text = "This is a good example";
List<String> split = text.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
  print(split.sublist(0, i + 1).join(" "));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  
  String str = "This is a good example";
  final split = str.split(" ");
  
  for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) {
    String result = "";
    for (int j = 0; j < i+1; j++) {
      result += split[j];
      if (j < i) { 
        result += " ";
      }
    }
    print(result);
  }
```

Result:

```
This
This is
This is a
This is a good
This is a good example
```

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this (easy way):

```
  String myString = "This is a good example";
  List<String> output = myString.split(" ");
  String prev = "";
  output.forEach((element) {
    prev += " " + element;
    print(prev);
  });
```

**Output:**

```
 This
 This is
 This is a
 This is a good
 This is a good example
```

---

If you'd like to simply split a string by word you could do it with the `split()` function:

```
String myString = "This is a good example";
List<String> output = myString.split(" ");
output.forEach((element) => print(element));
```

**Output:**

```
This
is
a
good
example
```

Comment: Presumably, using a StringBuffer is more efficient than += String concatenation in dart?

Comment: It is more efficient but unless you are concatenating millions of strings, you won't really notice a difference.